# How to redirect to different pages using a single form in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I was trying to design a form which can be used to redirect the user to corresponding pages as per the selected category field. i am new to django I'm not sure where the error can be. Therefore, I am sharing all four files i.e. models, views, forms and templates (The urls are correct).

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = False, blank = False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'name', unique = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to="pdfs/")
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name = 'pdftools',
        on_delete = models.SET_NULL,
        blank = True,
        null = True
        )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pdf}"
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
import forms
from django.contrib import messages
# from .models import Category
# from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
# from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.
def linkview(request):
    return render(request, 'Link.html')

def emailview(request):
    return render(request, 'Emails.html')

def textview(request):
    return render(request, 'Text.html')

def pdfUploadView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UploadPdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "File uploaded successfully!!")
            # return HttpResponse('The file is saved!')


            if category == 'Link':
                return redirect('link')
            elif category == 'Emails':
                return redirect('emails')
            elif category == 'Text':
                return redirect('text')
    else:
        form = forms.UploadPdfForm()
    
    return render(request, 'UploadPdf.html', {'form':form})
```

*UploadPdf.html*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="shadow p-3 mt-4 p-5 bg-dark text-white rounded mb-3">
            <center><h1>PdfXtract</h1></center>
        </div>
        <div class="card">

            <div class="shadow p-3 card-body">

                <form method = 'post' action="{% url 'UploadPdf' %}" enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

*forms.py*

```
from .models import Pdf
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UploadPdfForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ('category','pdf')
```

I was expecting to go to different pages while selecting values in the form. For eg:- 'Emails' should take me to Emails.html (named 'emails' in the url). But after uploading file I stay on the same page and keep uploading them unnecessarily.

Comment: Category is *not* a string, it is a `Category` object, hence `if category == 'Link':` will *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like below.

```
category = form.cleaned_data['category']
```

Here category is the id of category object. Not the text.

```
catg=Category.Objects.get(id=category) 
if catg.name == 'Link':
    return redirect('link')
```

I wouldn't say this code will work 100%. But this is enough to figure it out.

Comment: I am getting this typeerror : ' Field 'id' expected a number but got <Category: Link>'

Comment: I fixed it by making a slight change 'catg=Category.Objects.get(name=category)'. Thanks for the help!